# symbol not found in flat namespace '_png_do_expand_palette_rgb8_neon' Mac M1 Pycharm error

Tags: python-3.x, django, face-recognition, apple-m1, dlib

I am trying to use face_recognition for python in my django project but it does not seem to work as it is giving error when i write `import face-recognition` I am using it in pycharm, M1 macbook air, django rest framework. Following is the versions

- Python 3.8
- face_recognition 1.3.0
- dlib 19.23.0

here is error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_dlib_pybind11.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_png_do_expand_palette_rgb8_neon'
```

If anyone can help me solve this error or know any work around to get it working ?